# How does explicit coercion works in R?

Tags: r, explicit-conversion, type-coercion

I am trying to understand the **COERCION** in R programming language. When it comes to ***explicit coercion***, it states that we can convert from one class of vectors(considering general object) to another class.

Consider following,

```
> x <- c(1L, 0L, 3L)
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

So the class of x is integer here. Now we can convert it to logical as,

```
> as.logical(x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

So now the class of x should be logical as per the coercion, but when I again display the class of x as follows,

```
> as.logical(x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
> class(x)
[1] "integer"
```

How it is working? Please help me in understanding. And please correct my sentence 
***"So now the class of x should be logical as per the coercion***"

Comment: in your last call `class(x)`, `x` is still the first one with only integer because you did not assign the result of `as.logical`. Try `class(as.logical(x))`

Comment: otherwise you can try to override `x` : `x <- as.logical(x)`

Comment: @cderv, Thanks, I thought it will assign it back. Got the point now.